# Why recruitment agents keep asking if I have any other interviews planned

Tags: recruitment

I recently started looking for my next move, not all but most recruitment agents ask if I have any interviews lined up.

I don't understand why they ask and how it's relevant to them ?

When I ask them why they want to know, I get a very confusing answer e.g. they need to prioritize there timeline with there clients, which makes no sense ?

Am I losing something by not disclosing such information and am I gaining anything by telling them about this ?

Comment: Further clarification required.  A location tag would be helpful too.

Comment: I think Op means: "The interviewers ask me if I have any other interviews planned at the time." Like, they want to know if he's talking with other companies as well as that recruiter, just so they know whose likely to find a job before they can be placed or whatever.

Comment: Some recruiters don't get paid unless they place you in a position.

Answer (score 1):

The recruiter is asking you this so that they can gauge your reliability. You are their product and the employer is their client. A lot of what they ask you is to determine if you are the best product they can be giving their client.

This is a question that you should decline to answer as it has no bearing on your qualities as an employee.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I losing something by not disclosing such information and am I gaining anything by telling them about this ?

It's information, information is useful in many ways from gauging your saleability and timeframes to surveys. So the recruiter gains something.

You don't really gain anything except making things better for the recruiter, but you don't lose anything and have no reason to withhold that information.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you applied to a job post online and you got a call from a recruiter who is telling you all this.

You have to understand what a recruiter job is.Their job is to post jobs for their clients and gather resumes and give them to the client for review. It is up to the client on which person they want, but if they select someone through the recruiter, they get a cut of their total pay.

So reality is your "recruiter" isn't working for you. They want you to polish up your resume, ask for your schedule, then they submit the resume along with others. They're basically working for the client, not for you. In nearly 99% of cases where I applied to a recruiter's post, I don't actually apply to the company they advertise instead I get the exact phone calls as you do, then nothing ever happens. I never apply to a recruiter post and sometimes I accidentally do and I simply hang up and move along. I consider these type of posts as spam. I know I got "tricked" when I get a phone call 5 minutes after "applying."

My advice is to stop going to this recruiter and instead either apply directly with companies or continue to apply hoping to get someone.